# React Context API; Is it possible to access updated context from a sibling hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks, react-context

A button calls the function signAllBrowsed, which contains two other functions:

- loadSafetyLetters is a hook that makes a database call for some data and sets it in context
- signAll is a hook that tries to access data in context to do something with it

Context is getting set properly, but when signAll accesses it, the data is not updated. Is there a way to access the updated context without directly passing it to the 2nd function? Or is there a way to call a callback once context is updated and accessible? Seems the updated context is only available after a re-render.

The component containing signAllBrowsed and the 2 hooks are siblings.

[image]

code in above image:

```
        setModalVisible(true)
        const logHeader = 'SafetyLetterHome::SignAllBrowsed'
        try {
            const response = await loadSafetyLetters(false) // before beginning sign all, get a fresh list of letters from db
            if (Configs.SHOW_REQUEST_LOGS) console.log(`${logHeader} response`, response)
            if (response === 'no api error') {
                await signAll()
                navigation.navigate('SafetyLetterSign')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            const errorMessage = error.status && error.status.message ? error.status.message : error
            Alert.alert('Database Error', errorMessage)
            console.log(`${logHeader}`, errorMessage)
        }
    }
```

loadSafetyLetters calls the loadLetters hook:

```
    const [getLetters] = useGetLetters()
    const [sortLetters] = useSortLetters()
    const [hasAPIError] = useHasAPIError()
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    const { setModalVisible, setShowSignAll, setSortedLetters, setUnsortedLetters } = useContext(SafetyContext)

    const loadLetters = async (sort = true) => {
        try {
            const response = await getLetters()
            const logHeader = 'SafetyHome::loadLetters'
            const errorMessage = 'The following error occurred when trying to load letters:'
            if (Configs.SHOW_REQUEST_LOGS) console.log(`${logHeader} response`, response)

            const error = hasAPIError(response, logHeader, errorMessage)
            if (error) return error

            const { data } = response.data.payload
            let unsortedLetters = []
            if (data !== null && data.length > 0) {
                data.map((item) => {
                    // grab only unsigned letters
                    if (
                        item.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.PENDING ||
                        item.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.BROWSED ||
                        item.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.QUESTIONS_COMPLETE
                    ) {
                        unsortedLetters.push({
                            safetyLetterId: item.safetyLetterId,
                            title: item.title,
                            assignmentStatus: item.assignmentStatus,
                            filePath: item.filePath,
                            embeddableToken: item.embeddableToken,
                            sponsorId: item.sponsorId,
                            letterDate: item.letterDate,
                            form16: item.form16Enabled === '1' ? true : false,
                            sponsorName: item.sponsorName,
                            type: item.letterType,
                            sortOrder: item.sortOrder,      // dear doctor; sortOrder === 1
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
            if (unsortedLetters.length > 0) {



                let bletters = unsortedLetters.filter((letter) => letter.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.BROWSED || letter.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.QUESTIONS_COMPLETE)
                console.log('useLoadLetters; setting fresh pull of letters in context, including ', bletters.length, ' browsed letters')



                setUnsortedLetters(unsortedLetters)     // set in context
                setShowSignAll(                             // show/hide sign all button
                    unsortedLetters.some((letter) =>
                        letter.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.BROWSED ||
                        letter.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.QUESTIONS_COMPLETE,
                    ))
            }

            if (sort) {
                if (unsortedLetters.length > 0) {
                    let sortedLetters = sortLetters(unsortedLetters) // sort letters with hook
                    setSortedLetters(sortedLetters) // set in context
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('SafetyHome::loadLetters ', error)
            const errorMessage = error.status && error.status.message ? error.status.message : error
            Alert.alert(
                'Error Loading Letters',
                `A database error has occurred. Please try again. (${errorMessage})`,
            )
            navigation.navigate('Home')
        } finally {
            setModalVisible(false)
        }
    }

    return [loadLetters]
}
```

signAll hook:

```
    const { state: { unsortedLetters },
        setF16Browsed,
        setQcAndBrowsed,
        setModalVisible,
        setSelectedLetter
    } = useContext(SafetyContext)

    const signAll = async () => {
        let qcAndBrowsed = []           // set letter groups in context
        let f16Browsed = []
        unsortedLetters.forEach((letter) => {
            if (
                letter.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.BROWSED ||
                letter.assignmentStatus === SafetySources.QUESTIONS_COMPLETE
            ) {
                if (
                    letter.form16 &&
                    letter.assignmentStatus !== SafetySources.QUESTIONS_COMPLETE
                ) {
                    f16Browsed.push(letter)
                } else {
                    qcAndBrowsed.push(letter)
                }
            }
        })
        setQcAndBrowsed(qcAndBrowsed)
        setF16Browsed(f16Browsed)

        // begin sign all with first f16 letter
        if (f16Browsed.length > 0) {
            setSelectedLetter(f16Browsed[0])
        } else {
            setSelectedLetter(null)         // clear any previous viewed letter
        }
        setModalVisible(false)
    }

    return [signAll]
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code for those methods, as well as where the provider for this context is rendered? Like if it's properly wrapped around both

Comment: The context provider wraps around the navigator, which wraps around the components above (I am using React Native stack navigator). Context is working fine elsewhere; I think the issue is accessing updated context without re-rendering, i.e. inside the signAllBrowsed function. @webdevdani

Comment: I came up with a solution but it requires an additional render. As before, loadSafetyLetters updates context. Instead of calling signAll immediately after, I called it from a useEffect, which triggers when context changes. The only problem is that context updates in cases when I don't want to call signAll. So I need a local state 'flag' to turn signAll off and on. Turning it on causes another render.

Comment: IMO waiting for the context to update and calling the second action from a `useEffect` is the right approach.